# Unable to create database in PostreSQL using Npgsql and Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

I am attempting to set up my application to use Entity Framework with PostgreSQL, but I have run up against a problem. I have added `Npqsql` via nuget, and added the following provider factory to `web.config`:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" 
           invariant="Npgsql" 
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql Server" 
           type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, 
                 Version=2.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, 
                 PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

With the connection string:

```
    <add name="MyDb" providerName="Npgsql" 
connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=withoomph;User ID=postgres;Password=******;enlist=true" />
```

It seems to connect to the DB fine, but when I try and do any sort of action on the DB I get the following exception:

`FATAL: 3D000: database "withoomph" does not exist`

I am setting the database intitializer correctly when the db is set up like so:

```
static MyDB()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<MyDB>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDB>());
}
```

So it should just simply create db when I try and do anything with my `DbContext` right? I don't get it, been pulling my hair out all morning!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, Npgsql does not have (as of now) automatic schema creation code-first.

You can create your database first, and then connect to it.

Update (2016): Npgsql 3 now implements database creation code-first. Make sure you configure the correct connection factory to use `NpgsqlConnection`s, either via code or via the XML settings, and use an appropriate [Connection String](https://www.connectionstrings.com/npgsql/).

Comment: At last after god knows how much trawling the internet i have finally been given the precise reason why this is happening! Thank you, at least now I know it's either DB-first with pgsql, or code first with something else :-)

Comment: Adding a comment nearly 2 years after my answer... New Npgsql 2.2.0 version includes support for migrations and codefirst with EF6

Comment: May i ask how? I used nuget to install Npgswl.Entityframework (v 2.2.5). This installed also EF6 and npqsql 2.2.5 . I got an exception that dbo.xyz is not available. using (DataAccessContext db = new DataAccessContext(dbConnection))
            {
                IObjectContextAdapter adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)db;
                string script = adapter.ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript(); -> Excepton :"CreateDatabaseScript is not supported by the provider."

Comment: I'm a little confused. are you saying once the database exists, EF actually does create tables from entities in code first? Because I couldnt get npgsql to create tables either.

Comment: With current EntityFramework (6.1.3) and EntityFramework6.Npgsql (3.0.5) from NuGet, and with proper user permission (in my case a classical super user), I get the full database creation from an empty postgresql setup. It was not possible in 2013, when this answer was first added.

Comment: @AlexMazzariol do you have some sample for db creation with EF6 and npgsql? Do you have a code snippet?

Comment: I believe any example DbContext with any typical DbSet will work.. As of now, I have half a dozen .NET business apps (web apps) being hosted on linux and using PostgreSQL as RDBMS. Are you having specific problems? If this is the case, please open another question :)

Comment: @AlexMazzariol no I haven't no particular problem, I'm integrating postgresql in a .net app and I'm noob on Entity Framework, so I'm searching for good documentation or good samples/snippets.

Answer (score 4):

Not surprisingly, since your database `withoomph` is not created yet, you should not able to use connection string where `Database=withoomph;` is mentioned.

What you can do is to either create this database manually using `createdb` or `psql`, or change your connection string temporarily to use `Database=postgres;` instead.

This should work because on all recent PostgreSQL versions database `postgres` is guaranteed to exist after vanilla install and should be used just for this purpose - to get initial authenticated connection to create another database and issue `CREATE DATABASE withoomph;` within your application.

However, after your new database is created, you should immediately disconnect from `postgres`, connect to new `withoomph` and continue normally.

Comment: Ok, I will try it out. It has thrown me because this is different behavior than every other type of SQL db I have attempted to use EF with, there's not much information about on how to do this as well. I shall report back.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to mvp's answer, here's a code snippet I used to create the database. You need to run it before initializing EF.
So, the trick is to switch the database name temporarily to 'postgres', which is guaranteed to exists after a vanilla install.

```
public void CreateDatabase(string connectionString)
{
    var builder = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
    var databaseName = builder.Database; // REMEMBER ORIGINAL DB NAME
    builder.Database = "postgres"; // TEMPORARILY USE POSTGRES DATABASE

    // Create connection to database server
    using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        // Create database
        var createCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
        createCommand.CommandText = string.Format(@"CREATE DATABASE ""{0}"" ENCODING = 'UTF8'", databaseName);
        createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same issue. Was wondering where you get this method triggered? On the initializer? I followed the instruction where I changed the web.config to "postgres", but now it's checking postgres database and does not trigger my initializer. Should I be putting this on the global.asax.cs? Thank you!

Comment: I usually have a separate console in which I perform such opertions. You could put it in the global.asax in the app start, but then you should check if the database exists first, otherwise it will recreate your database every time you start the application :)