# Create Database from EDMX file in EF6 + PostGres

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6, postgresql-9.4

I need to create Database (along with Schema) from EDMX file in Entity Framework 6 + PostGres. I'm using Npgsql.2.2.5.

I tried to create it using below code.

```
using(var ctx = new DatabaseContentEntities()){
    ctx.CreateDatabase();
}
```

But it was giving me an error message like

> CreateDatabase is not supported by the provider

Do the Npgsql support this, if yes please Can anyone tell me how can I solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is DatabaseContentEntities?

Comment: Looks like it you will need to create the db first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379288/unable-to-create-database-in-postresql-using-npgsql-and-entity-framework-code-fi

Comment: DatabaseContentEntities is my Class that extends ObjectContext. @natemcmaster

Comment: It was working fine with SQLServer. Do postgres support this? @SteveGreene